# 404 when loging in IdentityServer 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

As many people I am struggling to set up identity server. Here is my situation as I haven't found a suitable solution

- I have one solution containing the MVC Client (.net core 2.1)
- I have a separate solution containing the code related to IdentityServer

Everything seems to work fine to verify the user credentials but when I want to redirect after login succeeds it results in a 404 page not found.
Below the code to give more information

**LoginController from the IdentityServer solution**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginDto login)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Missing email or password");

        try
        {
            var loginModel = Map(login);
            var user = await _loginService.LoginAsync(loginModel);

            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName));
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (UserNotFoundException)
        {
            return BadRequest("User not found");
        }
        catch (LoginFailedException)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
        catch (AccountLockedOutException)
        {
            return StatusCode((int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }

    private static LoginModel Map(LoginDto login)
    {
        return new LoginModel
        {
            Email = login.Email,
            Password = login.Password,
            RememberMe = login.RememberMe
        };
    }
```

**The configuration from the Startup class of Identity solution**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServer"));
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityServerDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "Miricle.IdentityServer.Api";
            });

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
        services.AddScoped<IApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationSignInManager>();
        services.AddScoped<IApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUserManager>();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicyName, policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
                policy.AllowCredentials();
            });
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        app.UseCors(CorsPolicyName);
    }
}
```

**The LoginController from the .NET Core MVC Client**

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public LoginController(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = new LoginViewModel();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] LoginViewModel login)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Index", login);

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
            .Accept
            .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:44374/api/login");

        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LoginViewModel()
        {
            Email = login.Email,
            Password = login.Password,
            RememberMe = login.RememberMe,
        });
        request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return Redirect("/Home/Index");
    }

}
```

**The configuration from the Startup of the MVC Client**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "Miricle.Crm.Web";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("Miricle.IdentityServer.Api");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });

        services.AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
        .AddRazorViewEngine()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicyName, policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
                policy.AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" });
        });

        app.UseCors(CorsPolicyName);
    }
}
```

I have been trying to get that work for nearly a week now and I am sure it is something stupid but I can't find it :/

Comment: For what url it shows 404?

Comment: Well, what step exactly throws 404? Also, that's a very weird IdSrv implementation, you never login the user to the client application

Comment: The 404 happens for all the routes having Authorize in the controller (which I have set up globally). What do you mean by I never login the user to the client application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your code is trying to do but from the description of your intended aim then I would expect to see

- MVC Client with a Controller or Controller method that is protected with the [Authorize] attribute
- Identity server that includes a Controller and View for the login screen that redirects back to the client after authentication

There is an example the covers exactly what your are trying to do at

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html

but if you don't want to work through the example then you can go directly to the working code:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication

Comment: I wanted to have the UI separated from IdentityServer. I have done more research on the subject and I understand one of the comment saying that it was a weird implementation of IdentityServer :). Thanks for the links